# How to price an inflation caplet/floorlet using Bachelier Formula?

Tags: pricing, caplet, cap

I am trying to recalculate the prices of inflation cap in order to calibrate a SABR model.
I have this table which gives me the normal volatilities values in % for the different strikes and different maturities.

[image]

I have this curve of forward rate :

[image]

And finally I have this table which gives me the cap prices in bp :
[image]

I use this function in order to recalculate the prices but I have a slight difference of a couple of bps between the prices given and the prices I obtain by manual calculation :
[image]

I know there has been a couple of questions about this but I've been stuck on this calculation for a few days if someone could help me obtain the right result with complete explanation it would be very nice !

Comment: You might get quicker responses if you show what you did so far. As of now, it looks like nothing was done and there is only a copy pasted (homework) question.

Comment: Here is the calculations I've done so far for example for the 1yr caplet at 2% strike :
fwd - K = 0.027575-0.02=0.007575
d = 0.007575/(0.0225*Sqr(1)) = 0.3366667
N(d) = 0.631815903
n(d) = 0.376962052
Put it together and you obtain :
Caplet = 0.007575*0.631815903 + 0.0225*Sqr(1)*0.376962052 = 0.005019887
This is not equal to the number I should obtain which would be 0.01214.
What are the errors I'm doing in my calculation because I really don't manage to find the good formula to calculate the price of the caplets ?

Comment: I know it's a bit late but anyone knows ?